# Using purrr to iterate over two lists and then pipe into dplyr::filter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
```

Using the sample data below, I can create the following function:

```
Funs <- function(DF, One, Two){

    One <- enquo(One)
    Two <- enquo(Two)

    DF %>% filter(School == (!!One) & Code == (!!Two)) %>%
        group_by(Code, School) %>%
        summarise(Count = sum(Question1))
}
```

I can then use the function to filter on two variables - School and Code - like this:

```
Funs(DF, "School1", "B344")
```

That's all good, but my actual data has many variables and therefore instead of having to constantly type the "School" and "Code" variables into the function, I would like to use tidyverse and the purrr package to loop over two lists (one of School, and one for Code) and feed this into filter. I would like the output to be a list of results.

For the sake of simplicity, the two lists to feed into dplyr::filter will only have two values each: School2 will go with S300, and School1 with B344, just like the example above.

Some examples that I've tried:

```
map2(c(“School2”, ”School1”),
     c(“S300”, ”B344”),
     function(x,y) {
         DF %>% filter(School == .x & Code == .y) %>%
             group_by(Code, School) %>%
             summarise(Count = sum(Question1))
     }
```

Also...

```
map2(c("School2", "School1")),
     c("S300","B344"),
     ~filter(School == .x & Code == .y) %>%
         group_by(Code, School)%>%
         summarise(Count = sum(Question1))
```

And this...

```
list(c("School2", "School1"), c("S300", "B344")) %>%
    map2( ~ filter(School == .x & Code == .y) %>%
             group_by(Code, School) %>%
             summarise(Count = sum(Question1)))
```

None of these seem to work, so help would be appreciated!

Sample data:

```
Code <- c("B344","B555","S300","T220","B888","B888","B555","B344","B344","T220","B555","B555","S300","B555","S300","S300","S300","S300","B344","B344","B888","B888","B888")
School <- c("School1","School1","School2","School3","School4","School4","School1","School1","School3","School3","School4","School1","School1","School3","School2","School2","School4","School2","School3","School4","School3","School1","School2")
Question1 <- c(3,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,4,3,3,3,4,5,4,3,3)
Question2 <- c(5,4,3,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,4,3,4,4,5,4,3,3,4)
DF <- data_frame(Code, School, Question1, Question2)
```

Comment: You could do something like `map2(c("School2", "School1"), c("S300", "B344"), ~DF %>% filter(School == .x, Code == .y) %>%
              group_by(Code, School) %>%
              summarise(Count = sum(Question1)))`, but this seems really pointless; it's easier to do something like `DF %>% filter(paste(School, Code) %in% paste(c("School2", "School1"), c("S300", "B344"))) %>%
              group_by(Code, School) %>%
              summarise(Count = sum(Question1))`

Comment: It looks like your first suggestion is what I was looking for. I realize now that using map2_df is probably better. Also, it's probably better for me to create two lists, like list1<-c("School2","School1") and list2<-c("S300","B344") and then using these since my actual data has at least a dozen values for each list. So I'm thinking this... map2_df(list1,list2, ~df%>%filter(School==.x,Code==.y)%>%group_by(Code,School)%>%summarise(Count=sum(Question1)))

Comment: I can accept your first response if you post it as an official answer. Also, I'm curious to know why you think the second suggestion is better? The output was probably better, but I can use map2_df for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some options, from most like your code to most optimal:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data_frame(Code = c("B344", "B555", "S300", "T220", "B888", "B888", "B555", "B344", "B344", "T220", "B555", "B555", "S300", "B555", "S300", "S300", "S300", "S300", "B344", "B344", "B888", "B888", "B888"), 
                 School = c("School1", "School1", "School2", "School3", "School4", "School4", "School1", "School1", "School3", "School3", "School4", "School1", "School1", "School3", "School2", "School2", "School4", "School2", "School3", "School4", "School3", "School1", "School2"), 
                 Question1 = c(3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3), 
                 Question2 = c(5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4))

wanted <- data_frame(School = c("School2", "School1"),
                     Code = c("S300", "B344"))
```

To get `map2` to work, if using tilde notation, the variables are named `.x` and `.y`; if you use regular function notation, you can call them whatever you like. Don't forget that the first parameter of `filter` is the data frame piped in, so:

```r
map2_dfr(wanted$School, wanted$Code, ~filter(DF, School == .x, Code == .y)) %>% 
    group_by(School, Code) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups: School [?]
#>   School  Code  Question1 Question2
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 School1 B344       7.00      8.00
#> 2 School2 S300      15.0      14.0
```

Since I set up `wanted` as a data frame (a vanilla list would work too), you can use `pmap` instead. Parameter names with `pmap` can actually be the same as `map2` for two variables, but it's really a function with `...` for its parameters, so it often makes sense to handle them differently, e.g. with `..1` notation:

```r
wanted %>% 
    pmap_dfr(~filter(DF, School == ..1, Code == ..2)) %>% 
    group_by(School, Code) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups: School [?]
#>   School  Code  Question1 Question2
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 School1 B344       7.00      8.00
#> 2 School2 S300      15.0      14.0
```

The problem with both of the above techniques is that at scale, they will be slow, because they are running `filter` for every row of `wanted`, meaning you're retesting each row many times. To keep the code similar, a slightly hacky way to avoid the extra work is to combine the columns into one, e.g. with `tidyr::unite`:

```r
DF %>% 
    unite(school_code, School, Code) %>% 
    filter(school_code %in% invoke(paste, wanted, sep = '_')) %>%    # or paste(wanted$School, wanted$Code, sep = '_') or equivalent
    separate(school_code, c('School', 'Code')) %>%
    group_by(School, Code) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups: School [?]
#>   School  Code  Question1 Question2
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 School1 B344       7.00      8.00
#> 2 School2 S300      15.0      14.0
```

...or just combine them within `filter` itself:

```r
DF %>% 
    filter(paste(School, Code) %in% paste(wanted$School, wanted$Code)) %>%    # or invoke(paste, wanted)
    group_by(School, Code) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups: School [?]
#>   School  Code  Question1 Question2
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 School1 B344       7.00      8.00
#> 2 School2 S300      15.0      14.0
```

The *best* way to get your desired result is perhaps more obvious now that I've set up `wanted` as a data frame: a join, which is designed to do precisely this job:

```r
DF %>% 
    inner_join(wanted) %>% 
    group_by(School, Code) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> Joining, by = c("Code", "School")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups: School [?]
#>   School  Code  Question1 Question2
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 School1 B344       7.00      8.00
#> 2 School2 S300      15.0      14.0
```

Comment: Just copy/pasted this answer into an R Markdown notebook so that I could run/understand each step (because I have a similar problem).  When I got to the end and saw the `inner_join` I couldn't believe how truly simple and elegant it should've been for me to solve my similar problem!